# Hide all site templates except custom and also show templates which are added after feature activation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature, feature-activation, sharepoint-server

We want to remove all site templates except custom templates under **Create > 'Sites and Workspaces'.** and we only want to allow custom templates... Custom template can grow over the time by saving site as template.

When I activate below feature code it removes all other templates as required and only shows custom templates but if I save site as template which creates new custom template... new custom template doesn't appear under **Create > 'Sites and Workspaces'.**

How can my feature look for newly created templates?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;    // Get the SPWeb object for current site
        uint lang = web.Language;
        web.AllowAllWebTemplates(); // Resets the available Web templates on the Web site to the complete set of Web templates.

        SPWebTemplateCollection existingWebTemps = web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(lang);
        Collection<SPWebTemplate> newWebTemps = new Collection<SPWebTemplate>();

        for (int i = 0; i < existingWebTemps.Count; i++)
        {
            if (existingWebTemps[i].IsCustomTemplate)
            {
                newWebTemps.Add(existingWebTemps[i]);
            }
        }

        web.SetAvailableWebTemplates(newWebTemps, lang);
        web.Update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I made a similar feature not long ago and I was able to achieve this
>   by looking at all existing templates and matching the names against
>   the know out of the box templates. If the current template is one of
>   those then hide it. It's very cumbersome but it works.
>
> You need to list each template by name so a bit tedious...
>
> Just to add, I do have the code somewhere so I can dig it out and post
>   it here when I get a chance.

I see that you are taking the reverse approach of hiding not required templates instead of showing templates which are required and making them available.

I had thought about that option but because of nature of the solution I was trying to come up with some simpler solution but thanks for the reply if nothing else I'll have to go that route. :)

I was wondering can we not program something where we show items based on **DisplayCategory** i.e. Collaboration, Meetings, Publishing, Custom etc.? It's not working for me.

Comment: I see that you are taking the reverse approach of hiding not required templates instead of showing templates which are required and making them available.

I had thought about that option but because of nature of the solution I was trying to come up with some simpler solution but thanks for the reply if nothing else I'll have to go that route. :)

I was wondering can we not program something where we show items based on **DisplayCategory** i.e. Collaboration, Meetings, Publishing, Custom etc.? It's not working for me.

Comment: Hi again, to be honest for that I worked on that wouldn't have met our requirements as we wanted certain templates hidden only so we had to name each one. I was able to make the job a bit easier by checking if the name contained a word such as 'database' to hide a group of templates rather than making each database site template. Good luck.